# How can I utilize XAML objects specified in a resource dictionary in other XAML source?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If i have a resource dictionary that contains something like

```
<RibbonTab x:Key="HomeRibbonComponent" Header="test">

</RibbonTab>
```

how can I have my Ribbon control add this as a child? (in code it seems easy, in XAML not so much...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the resource extension directly as if you were binding it but in XAML.

e.g.,

```xaml
<StaticResource ResourceKey="HomeRibbonComponent" />
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing strange about this, it's just another syntax. (The `Extension` can be dropped from the tag by the way)